# Cannot get the WCF Test Client to work

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I am using the WCF Test Client. When I go to 'add service' and select a service to add I get this message,

Assembly Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Hosting, Version 1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 was not found. Reinstall the assembly or Visual Studio. The application cannot continue and will exit.

The service I am using is on the web, i.e. it is not being hosted locally on my machine. It is also using https.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should reinstall the `Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Hosting` (or Visual Studio), as this assembly is missing. This has nothing to do with the web service, the assembly to consume a service is not installed.

Comment: OK, thanks. But that is just what the message says. How can I reinstall that assembly? I have been developing this web service on my machine including writing client code to test the service. So I am finding it hard to believe that using this tool wouldn't work because the assembly to 'consume' a service is not installed.

Comment: Something doesn't quite add up.

Comment: Hm, okay. Out of my area of expertise then, never have dealt with it before, it just sounded like it.